# How to display minus on the left (Delphi, TListview)

Tags: delphi, vcl, bidi

I'm trying to display the minus symbol of a negative number on the left side of an Item in a `TListview` that has his property `BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft.`

I tried the code there:

[Thousand Separator in DBGrid](http://thehelpcentre.xyz/question/21549666/thousand-separator-in-dbgrid)

```
Function TfrmProjets.IfSign(floatValue: double; howMuchDecimalAfterComa: 

integer):string;
var
  strResult: string;
  strZero: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  strResult := '';
  strZero := '';

  for i := 0 to howMuchDecimalAfterComa -1 do
  begin
    strZero := strZero + '0';
  end;

  if(Sign(floatValue) = NegativeValue)then
  begin
      strResult := '-' + FormatFloat('0.' + strZero,Abs(floatValue));
    //strResult := '(' + FormatFloat('0.' + strZero,Abs(floatValue)) + ')';
  end
  else
  begin
    strResult := FormatFloat('0.' + strZero,floatValue);
  end;

  result := strResult;
end;
```

And in fact it work when I use breakpoint to evaluate `strResult`.

But when it come to `TListView` display in my item:

```
lvItem := lvPeriodic[0];
lvItem.SubItems.Add(IfSign(-14.2),1) + '%') ;
```

It display like this: `14.2%-`

Is there a way to tell the `TListview` not to change the string I'm displaying or something?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?  Unicode offers some solutions which are not available before D2009.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a unicode version of delphi, you can supply explicit RTL and LTR marks to force the position of language neutral or weak characters (like dash `-`, exclamation `!`, etc).

The rules for parsing LTR and RTL text in various contexts are extensive and complex.  For reference you can find the [bidirectional algorithm specification here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#S). One pass for weak characters does parse European numbers as LTR (which is why `14.2%` ends up in the correct direction, but the use of the dash `-` to indicate minus introduces ambiguity.  One would think that substituting a proper minus sign `U+2212` would work but this is also a weak character, presumably because arabic numbers can be negative as well (and would need to be rendered in the opposite direction...I'm not sure).

In any case - moving on, we can construct a function like this to force a string into a strict LTR order :

```
function StrictLTR(const s : string) : string;
const
  LTR_EMBED = Char($202A);
  POP_DIRECTIONAL = Char($202C);
begin
  result := LTR_EMBED + s + POP_DIRECTIONAL;
end;
```

This places an embedded Left-To-Right character (`U+202A`) before the string and follows it with a Pop-Directional-Formatting (`U+202C`) character.  The latter removes the embedded directional formatting cue and returns the text direction to whatever it was in the previous context.  The returned string, therefore, is safe to use in either an RTL or LTR context.

Calling this, then :

```
 ListView1.AddItem(StrictLTR(IfSign(-14.2,1) + '%'), nil);
```

Will produce the desired result.

---

As an aside, your `IfSign` function can be greatly simplified by using the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function :

```
Function IfSign(floatValue: double; numberOfDecimalPlaces:integer):string;
begin
  result := Format('%.'+IntTostr(numberOfDecimalPlaces)+'f', [floatValue]);
end;
```

Comment: I used your function and it works like a charm! I'm not sure I understand the pop-directional-formatting thought. Is this problematic a common thing to fix while programming? Thanks you very much for your advanced answer!

Comment: @pikarie the first `LTR_EMBED` character tells the parser to begin treating the following text as left-to-right text.  The `pop-directional-formatting` character tells the parser to stop forcing the text as LTR and to resume treating text afterwards as whatever bidi-mode it was before the `LTR_EMBED` character.  And yes, when mixing bi-directional text this is a normal way to enforce rendering of text that should be interpreted as a given direction.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks again!